# What is the toric code?

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics

The toric code is a basic computational model as follows:

[image]

There are 2 operations that can be performed, A and B, on this grid.

To compute the value A at each point on the grid, we transform the raw values at each dot (located in between two vertices) according to some predefined operators $f_a$ and $f_b$, and multiply the four surrounding values from the operations:

$$ A = f_a(left) f_a(up) f_a(right) f_a(down) $$
$$ B = f_b(left) f_b(up) f_b(right) f_b(down) $$

This seems to be a straightforward question, but I could no find a clear answer anywhere.

What confuses me is what type of *quantity* is prescribed at each dot, be it a scalar $0.24$, or a complex number $0.24 + 0.12 i$, or a vector $[0.24, 0.12]$?

Also what is the form of the operator function $f_a$ and what is $f_b$, be they 2x2 matrices, or something else?

Comment: I don't see how we should be able to know this. It would depend on what encoding the author has in mind as well as what operations they might have in mind.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I am new to this as well. There seems to be a very specific toric code by Kitaev that is the standard used in physics: https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/602/Lectures/JC_Presentations/0419/Intro_Toric_Code.pdf , Could you look for a bit and help?